# Remove Index from JSON object returned from database

Tags: arrays, json, database, object, hana

I have a JSON object that is returned from a database query as follows:

```
{"0":
      {"DSName":"Patients"},
 "1":
      {"DSName":"Doctors"},
 "2":
      {"DSName":"Nurses"}
}
```

I need to remove the index values 0,1,2 so that i only have the "DSName" values.

Result :

```
{
 {"DSName":"Patients"},
 {"DSName":"Doctors"},
 {"DSName":"Nurses"}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to index then do proper encoding of an array.

If you are encoding key value pair array then use array_values function and encode the values.

```
json_encode(array_values($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do so by using the Object function in javascript.
since you have eg

```
let f =  
{"0":
      {"DSName":"Patients"},
 "1":
      {"DSName":"Doctors"},
 "2":
      {"DSName":"Nurses"}
}
```

using **Object.values(f)** will give

```
[ { DSName: 'Patients' }, { DSName: 'Doctors' } ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myObj ={"0":
      {"DSName":"Patients"},
 "1":
      {"DSName":"Doctors"},
 "2":
      {"DSName":"Nurses"}
}

Single delete 

delete myObj['0']

For all element loop

for(var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
    delete myObj[i];
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying .. Property 0 is non-configurable and can't be deleted. On the other hand i suppose this would delete the whole node whereas i just need to remove the 0 , 1 and the 2.

Comment: Your solution is out of track..  he wants to remove only index not the values.